# Why does this JavaScript code print "undefined" on the console?

Tags: javascript, undefined, read-eval-print-loop

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var counter = 0;
function printCounter(){
   console.log("counter=" + ++counter);
   setTimeout(printCounter, 1000);
}
printCounter();
```

I expect that it should print this output:

```
counter=1
counter=2
counter=3
...
```

But instead it prints following:

```
counter=1
undefined  // <-- Notice this "undefined"
counter=2
counter=3
...
```

Why does it print "undefined" after the first iteration?

Important: I see such behavior *only* when the code executed in the JavaScript console. If it's the part of a page, it works fine.

Comment: The real canonical question is probably *[Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because the "printCounter()" function itself returns `undefined`. That's the console telling you the result of the expression.

Change "printCounter()" by adding `return "Hello Anton!";` to the end :-)

It's a little confusing to say it "returns `undefined`"; really, it has no explicit return, but it's the same effect.

Comment: ...and so the `undefined` is the result of *the REPL evaluation* but since the *asynchronous* timer is running it will continue to call `console.log`...

Comment: Yes, thank you, you are right. I was confused because it's not the case for all browsers.