# Why does a construction like '}{' in the Firefox and Chrome console return 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

If I type

```
}{
```

in the console of Firefox or Chrome, the result is **undefined**, *not* a SyntaxError.

This construction return **undefined** (construction like }!{ return false). What is the reason for such behavior?

Comment: I partially updated your question - would be a good idea to clarify what the latter part of your question means. (interesting observation, don't know the answer)

Comment: Yeah, but what does Internet Explorer say?

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Why does this JavaScript code print "undefined" on the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263190/why-does-this-javascript-code-print-undefined-on-the-console)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you enter [`debugger;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) in the console, a break point shows up, which reveals the answer:

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
debugger;
}
```

In Chrome's developer tools, the input is wrapped inside a `with` block, then literally evaluated. So, when you put in `}{`, the following is evaluated:

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
}{
}
```

This is an empty `with` block, followed by an empty block.

Exercise to reader: Try `}for(;;){`