# Why does Chrome & FireFox console print 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Take this simple Test object and paste it into the console. You'll see that it says `undefined`. The object is working because it also prints `123`, but what is the `undefined` about?

**Test:**

```
var Test = new (function(){
    return {
        get testing(){
            return "123";
        }
    }
});

console.log(Test.testing);
```

**Console Output:**

```
123
undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Why does this JavaScript code print "undefined" on the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263190/why-does-this-javascript-code-print-undefined-on-the-console)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the return value of `console.log`.

Try

```
console.log(1);
```

which gives

```
1
undefined
```

However, if you type just

```
Test.testing
```

that gives only

```
"123"
```

Answer (score 2):

`undefined` is the return value from the `console.log` call.