# javascript returning functional expressions vs declaring variables within a function

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, function-expression

Take the following function:

```
function createGlobalVar() {
y = "foo";
}

y //"foo"
```

in the absence of the keyword 'var', which would make y a local variable, the function climbs up the scope chain to try and find where y exists. Without any pre-existing declaration, it creates y as a global variable. Thus I don't need to add 'return y' at the end of my function in order for y to exist outside of it.

Now if I try to do the same thing, but assign a function expression to y, it won't work.

```
function createGlobalVar() {
y = function() { alert("foo!") }
}

y //"undefined"
```

I know how to correct it to make it work:

```
function createGlobalVar() {
y = function() { alert("foo!") }
return y;
}
var x = createGlobalVar();

x // function() { alert("foo!") }
```

But I don't understand WHY I have to return the global variable just because a functional expression was assigned to it. What's different?

Comment: Your code works for me ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEBez/)). Did you forget to call *createGlobalVar()*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263190/why-does-this-javascript-code-print-undefined-on-the-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `createGlobalVar` in your second example. There's no difference between assigning a function or a non-function expression to a property of a global object - and that's what happens when you write it like you did.

Note that using global object like this (unless you have *very* strong reasons) is discouraged. Have you wrote this function with the strict mode on, it would have thrown a ReferenceError on the line with `y`:

```
function createGlobalVar() {
  'use strict';
  y = function() { alert("foo!") };
}
createGlobalVar();

>> ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

You can always turn the function into either a setter (assigning some value to its context object property) or a function in the old-school definition of the word (i.e. a snippet of code that actually returns some meaningful value).

Comment: While it is true that this it most likely the problem, also in the first example `createGlobalVar` is not called, so both should not work.

Comment: Exactly: the first snippet wouldn't assign anything to a `global.y` unless the function is called actually.

Comment: Dammit you're right! Ugh stupid mistakes, I just needed an extra pair of eyes on it. Thanks!