# Understanding Object.assign behavior within for and forEach

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I noticed a strange behavior for Object.assign in the following case.

```js
function func1(idx, list) {
    list.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (i === idx) {
            console.log(Object.assign({}, {"key3": "value3"}, item));
            return Object.assign({}, {"key3": "value3"}, item); 
        }
    }); 
}

console.log(func1(0, [{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}]));
```

The output is

```
{
 "key3": "value3",
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value2"
}
undefined
```

Rather than

```
{
  "key3": "value3",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
{
  "key3": "value3",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

When the forEach is changed to for, the output is as expected

```js
function func2(idx, list) {
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        let item = list[i];
        if (i === idx) {
            console.log(Object.assign({}, {"key3": "value3"}, item));
            return Object.assign({}, {"key3": "value3"}, item); 
        }
    } 
}

console.log(func2(0, [{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}]));
```

Any explanation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this JavaScript code print "undefined" on the console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263190/why-does-this-javascript-code-print-undefined-on-the-console)

Comment: In the first example, the `return` statement returns from the `forEach` callback. In the second example, it returns from `func2()`. Yay arrow functions and their syntactic ambiguity with function scoping =)

Comment: you may use list.find or list[idx] ...

Comment: @Jonasw Not the issue..

Comment: @mhodges but it would make it much easier... just sharing good coding style...

Comment: `return`ing anything from `forEach` is absolutely pointless.

Comment: My solution simplifies this tremendously, I think it is what you're looking for, @Wahbivic

Comment: That's just a made-up example. There are many smarter ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your function doesn't return anything. Not returning anything is essentially returning `undefined`.

Next, even if you return the value of a `forEach` call, [`forEach` returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Lastly, `forEach` also does not support breaking using a return. `forEach` will run for each item in the array. Your `return` inside `forEach` has no meaning, except for short-circuiting the callback at that iteration only.

Answer (score 0):

forEach doesn't return you anything, the inner return in forEach has no meaning. You can make use of map to return value like

```js
function func1(idx, list) {
    return list.map((item, i) => {
        if (i === idx) {
            console.log(Object.assign({}, {"key3": "value3"}, item));
            return Object.assign({}, {"key3": "value3"}, item); 
        }
    }); 
}

console.log(func1(0, [{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}]));
```

or use a callback

```js
function myCallback(value) {
  console.log(value)
}
function func1(idx, list, callback) {
    return list.map((item, i) => {
        if (i === idx) {
            console.log(Object.assign({}, {"key3": "value3"}, item));
            callback(Object.assign({}, {"key3": "value3"}, item)); 
        }
    }); 
}

func1(0, [{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}], myCallback);
```

Comment: `.filter()[0]` would be more appropriate here, considering the OP is only wanting a single object returned

Comment: @mhodges yes that is also another method, but I think callback will also solve his problem

Answer (score 0):

you may want a bit shorter code that completely avoids the forEach:

```
func1=(i,list)=>Object.assign({key3:value3},list[i]||{});
```

You dont need to iterate over an Array and break at a certain index, you can simply access this element using bracket notation...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a specific index and not a property value or anything, you can very simply access the object you want from the list by saying `list[idx]`.

You should also consider swapping the order of your `Object.assign()` parameters, because it will overwrite properties from right to left. If `list[idx]` already has a `key3`, it will not assign it to the new value. Putting `{"key3": "value3"}` in the far right of the parameter list of `Object.assign()`ensures that value will get written to the object.

```js
function func1(idx, list) {
  console.log(Object.assign({}, list[idx], {"key3": "value3"}));
  return Object.assign({}, list[idx], {"key3": "value3"});
}

console.log(func1(0, [{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}]));
```