# Re-coding an undefined javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I "borrowed" this snippet from another site, and I've realized that it does not work when I try to use it. What is wrong with it?

```
var LessonsCustomControl = (function LessonsCustomControl_constructor(){

    var LessonTypes=[], LessonInterfaces={}, LessonsContent={};
    
    LessonInterfaces.ListQuiz1 = (function(typeClass){
        ...
    }

    function initListQuiz1(){
        LessonInterfaces.ListQuiz1('FITBPickOption').init();
    }

})();
```

In my code, when I try to call initListQuiz1(), I am getting nothing, i.e. LessonsCustomControl is undefined.  Need some help in rewriting this in valid javascript or jquery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this JavaScript code print "undefined" on the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263190/why-does-this-javascript-code-print-undefined-on-the-console)

Comment: `LessonsCustomControl_constructor` doesn't return anything, therefore you can't access anything that is generated inside that function, including `ListQuiz1`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even realize that for a whole week, but it is obvious.  I have re-written everything without the need for returning - this aspect was not suited for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The code you borrowed features encapsulation with an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression).

In order to use some functions from outside it, you have to `return` them:

```
var LessonsCustomControl = (function LessonsCustomControl_constructor(){

    var LessonTypes=[], LessonInterfaces={}, LessonsContent={};
    
    LessonInterfaces.ListQuiz1 = (function(typeClass){
        ...
    }

    function initListQuiz1(){
        LessonInterfaces.ListQuiz1('FITBPickOption').init();
    }

    return {
        initListQuiz1,
        // Other functions you need to "export"
    }

})();
```

Then call:

```
LessonsCustomControl.initListQuiz1();
```